# Enterprise Architect document template conditions like `if` and `else´

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, enterprise-architect, use-case

I'm working on my first Enterprise Architect custom document template to export our use cases considering the company design guidelines. Unfortunately, I am not able to print data based on certain conditions. E. g. hide fields with specific values or change their layout.

In my example or screenshot below I would like to hide `{ElemScenario.Type}` if the value is `Basic Path`, in example something like (I highlighted the position red):

```
if ({ElemScenario.Type} != "Basic Path") {
    {ElemScenario.Type}
}
```

[image]

How can I change the document template in Enterprise Architect with certain conditions? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter the content in the document options.
If you need only one type of scenario then you can do that in your main template, but  you'll probably want to make three separate template fragments, each showing only one specific type of scenario.

[image]

See also my article [Tutorial: Generate complex documents from Enterprise Architect with a two-step semi-automated approach](https://bellekens.com/2015/11/12/tutorial-generate-complex-documents-from-enterprise-architect-with-a-two-step-semi-automated-approach/) for a complete example of a use case template.